# Stream file from client to webrequest

Tags: c#, stream, webrequest

I'm working on a file upload from a c# web app, going from the client machine to a remote cloud host. The user types in the file name and location and passes that to the server. I am streaming the contents of the file in chunks to the request. However, the file is not valid when it gets to the destination. I'm sure it's somehow related to my request headers and junk like that, since I'm able to make this work when uploading from the server to the remote location. Can anyone spot what's wrong?

```
while (bytesRemaining > 0)
{
    if (!sw.CanRead)
    {
        sw = File.OpenRead(txtFileUpload.Text);
        if (offset > 0)
            sw.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }

    int count = sw.Read(buffer, 0, (int) chunk);

    request =
        (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create("http://xxxxxx.com/write/" +
                          offset);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ReadWriteTimeout = int.MaxValue;
    request.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

    var postData = new MemoryStream();
    const string newLine = "\r\n";
    var sw3 = new StreamWriter(postData);
    sw3.Write("--" + boundary + newLine);
    sw3.Write("Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"{0}\";filename=\"{1}\"{2}", "upload",
              txtFileName.Text, newLine);
    sw3.Write("Content-Type: multipart/form-data " + newLine + newLine);
    sw3.Flush();

    postData.Write(buffer, 0, count);
    sw3.Write(newLine);
    sw3.Write("--{0}--{1}", boundary, newLine);
    sw3.Flush();

    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
    using (Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
        postData.WriteTo(s);

    sw3.Write("--" + boundary + newLine);
    sw3.Write("Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"\"" + newLine);
    sw3.Write("content-type:octet-stream;charset=windows-1250" + newLine);

    sw3.Write("VALUE" + newLine);
    sw3.Write("--{0}--{1}", boundary, newLine);
    sw3.Flush();
    postData.Close();

    // These next 3 lines are what I had before, instead of all the previous
    // code, which worked when uploading a file from the server to the remote
    // location.
    //using (Stream sw2 = request.GetRequestStream())
    //{
    //    sw2.Write(buffer, 0, count);
    //}

    using (WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse())
    {
        resp.Close();
    }

    offset += count;
    bytesRemaining -= count;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel ? Use

```
WebClient.UploadFile
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile(v=vs.71).aspx

They even have an example.

Comment: I need to upload the file in chunks, since they're large (>=10 GB). I don't think WebClient.UploadFile supports that.

Comment: Also, I need to be able to pass an Authorization header to the request.

Comment: Anyone have any input on this? Pretty please!